# Hibernate session.save() is missing member from query

Tags: hibernate

Hiii guys
i'm building a simple ToDoList (this is just the beginning of the my project) that should add tasks to my schedule by using MAMP as DB.
my problem is the season.save()is missing the primary key from the query ("id" );
I have the following code:
main class:

```
 package Model;


    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;


    //create exception instead of HibernateException  ToDoListDAOException
    public class HibernateToDoListDAO implements IToDoListDAO {

        SessionFactory factory = null;
        private static final HibernateToDoListDAO _instanceDAO = new HibernateToDoListDAO();


        // no need to do connection or use driver to my sql
        private HibernateToDoListDAO(){
            factory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        }

        public static HibernateToDoListDAO getInstance()
        {
            return _instanceDAO;
        }

        @Override
        public void addMemorandums(items memorandum) throws HibernateException {
            Session session = factory.openSession();
            try{
                session.beginTransaction();
                //create the query for memorandum members
                session.saveOrUpdate(memorandum);
                System.out.println("after save : user id's = "+memorandum.getId());

                session.getTransaction().commit();
            }catch(HibernateException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if ( session.getTransaction() != null )
                    session.getTransaction().rollback();
            }finally{
                session.close();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void updateMemorandums(items memorandum) throws HibernateException {
            Session session = null;
            try{
                session = factory.openSession();
                session.beginTransaction();
                session.update(memorandum);
                session.getTransaction().commit();
            }catch(HibernateException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if ( session.getTransaction() != null )
                    session.getTransaction().rollback();
            }finally{
                session.close();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void deleteMemorandums(items memorandum) throws HibernateException {
            Session session = null;
            try{
                session = factory.openSession();
                session.beginTransaction();
                session.delete(memorandum);
                session.getTransaction().commit();
            }catch(HibernateException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if ( session.getTransaction() != null )
                    session.getTransaction().rollback();
            }finally{
                session.close();
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public List<items> getMemorandums() throws HibernateException {
            List<items> memorandum = null;
            Session session = null;
            try{
                session = factory.openSession();
                session.beginTransaction();
                memorandum = session.createQuery("from todolists").list();
            }catch(HibernateException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if ( session.getTransaction() != null )
                    session.getTransaction().rollback();
            }finally{
                session.close();
            } 
            return memorandum;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            String dateTask = "26/11/2016";
            items task1 = new items(2012,"football", dateTask , "ball");
            HibernateToDoListDAO.getInstance().addMemorandums(task1);

        }
    }
```

item class:

```
package Model;

import java.util.Date;

public class items {

    private int id;// primary key that connect to the users
    private String taskname;
    private String date;
    private String note;


    public items(){
        taskname = "basketball";
        note = "a fun game";
        date = "15/10/2016";
        id = 2012;
    }

    public items(int id, String taskName, String taskDate, String note) {
        super();
        this.taskname = taskName;
        this.date = taskDate;
        this.note = note;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTaskname() {
        return taskname;
    }

    public void setTaskname(String taskname) {
        this.taskname = taskname;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

i'm trying to run this simple program and i'm getting an exception that looks like:

(Exception)

```
Hibernate: insert into items (taskname, date, note) values (?, ?, ?)
org.hibernate.HibernateException: The database returned no natively generated identity value
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper.getGeneratedIdentity(IdentifierGeneratorHelper.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2329)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2836)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:677)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:669)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:665)
    at Model.HibernateToDoListDAO.addMemorandums(HibernateToDoListDAO.java:36)
    at Model.HibernateToDoListDAO.main(HibernateToDoListDAO.java:111)
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">
      org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
      com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   </property>

   <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
      jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hit
   </property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.username">hit</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.password">hit</property>
 <property name="show_sql">true</property>

 <!-- Mapping files -->
 <mapping resource="hibernate.mapping.xml"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

hibernate.mapping.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-mapping>

   <!-- *********** items table   ******* -->
<!-- full class name including the packege name -->
   <class name="Model.items" table="items">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains the the items details. 
      </meta>
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id"> <!-- primary key -->
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>

      <property name="taskname" column="taskname" type="string"/>
      <property name="date" column="date" type="string"/>
      <property name="note" column="note" type="string"/>
   </class>

   <!-- *********** users table   ******* -->

   <!-- full class name including the packege name -->

   <class name="Model.users" table="users">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains the users details. 
      </meta>
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
      <property name="age" column="age" type="int"/>
   </class>


</hibernate-mapping>
```

I'm using mamp as my DB (working with mysql).
the problem is that the query insert only three instead of four variables (missing the "id" member).
can someone help me to solve this issue?

thank you guys.

Comment: You need to `id` column as `auto increment` in your db. As you are learning, it is a good time to get familiar with java naming standards as well, here is the link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must auto increment the identity column of the table to get away with this error. Write the alter table query to have the identity column to auto increment. This should solve your problem